# Javascript simple if/else statement Quiz Game with 5 questions that outputs results at the end

Tags: javascript

Anyone care to help me get this code running correctly? Just simple if/else statements Javascript. I have tried attaching a "do {" before each of the next questions, but I couldn't get that to work. It keeps saying that "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

```
alert("Welcome to the 'Guess that Celebrities Age' Game! Let's see how many out of 5 you 
can guess right.")
let guess = 0;
let guess1 = 0;
let guess2 = 0;
let guess3 = 0;
let guess4 = 0;
let guess5 = 0;
let winsCounter = 0;
let losesCounter = 0;
do {
  guess = prompt("How old is Cher?");
  if (guess == 75) {
  alert("Correct! Cher is 75 years old. You guessed the number in tries.");
    winsCounter++;
}
  else {
    alert("Wrong! Sorry, better luck next time.");
    losesCounter++;
  }


 guess2 = prompt("How old is Elton John?");
  if (guess2 == 74) {
  alert("Correct! Elton John is 74 years old. You guessed the number in tries.");
    winsCounter++;
}
  else {
    alert("Wrong! Sorry, better luck next time.");
    losesCounter++;
  }


  guess3 = prompt("How old is Doja Cat?");
  if (guess3 == 26) {
  alert("Correct! Doja Cat is 26 years old. You guessed the number in tries.");
    winsCounter++;
}
  else {
    alert("Wrong! Sorry, better luck next time.");
    losesCounter++;
  }


  guess4 = prompt("How old is Christina Ricci?");
  if (guess4 == 42) {
  alert("Correct! Christina Ricci is 42 years old. You guessed the number in tries.");
    winsCounter++;
}
  else {
    alert("Wrong! Sorry, better luck next time.");
    losesCounter++;
  }


  guess5 = prompt("How old is Seth Rogan?");
  if (guess5 == 39) {
  alert("Correct! Seth Rogan is 39 years old. You guessed the number in tries.");
    winsCounter++;
}
  else {
   alert("Wrong! Sorry, better luck next time.");
    losesCounter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: `do` is part of a larger loop statement `do {...} while ()`. Without the `while` clause, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Hmmm. So do I need to create another variable counter and put a while statement just at the end?

Comment: Assuming you want to repeat the quiz until some exit condition is met, yes. You would put `while( condition )` at the very end, just outside the closing brace of the `do` block. However, if you don't want to repeat the quiz, you can just remove the do entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do` statement is incorrect. It needs the `while` keyword at the end.

So, you can change your code to the template below to get it working.

```js
let i = 0;
do {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
} while (i < 5)
```

Basically, after the `do` keyword, you can add your code in the curly braces.

However, at the end of the curly braces (*}*), you can then add the `while` keyword, and a boolean condition in the brackets (parentheses).

---

**Edit:** Here is the [documentation for `do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while).

Comment: To add, [here's the `do...while` statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while). If the asker doesn't require looping the code, they can just remove the `do` token and corresponding curly braces from the code.